# How to set Custom Headers in xrpl.js

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, cryptocurrency, xrp

I need to set custom headers for my requests in [xrpl.js](https://github.com/XRPLF/xrpl.js) in order to connect to a Blockchain Service with an API Key. I see that `ConnectionOptions` has an `authorization` field, which then is used as

```
options.headers = { Authorization: `Basic ${base64}` }
```

in `createWebSocket`, but my service requires

```
options.headers = { 'x-api-key': '<My API Key>' }
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`xrpl.js` is built to connect to the XRP Ledger. You won't have much success trying to connect to other services/APIs with `xrpl.js` .

The best way is to use a different library for such connections. There are many other libraries which lets you connect to APIs, such as `node-fetch`. They will also allow you to set custom headers.